# Returning a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, is it possible to return a function from within a function? I tried searching on Hoogle for:

```
(a -> b) -> a -> b
```

but couldn't find any functions that could achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure how existence of such function relates to the question in the first sentence. Anyway, there is a function with such signature - the identity function, specialized for type `a -> b` (since `(a -> b) -> a -> b` is the same as `(a -> b) -> (a -> b)`).

Comment: ...also called `($)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treating functions as first-class citizens is one of the advantages of Haskell and doesn't require any special syntax.

For example if you want to have a function which will double the result of given function you can write:

```
doubleFunction f = (\x -> 2 * (f x))
```

When given a function f, doubleFunction is equal to a function which multiplies (f x) by 2. You can write it using function composition:

```
doubleFunction f = (* 2) . f
```

or even shorter:

```
doubleFunction = ((* 2) .)
```

doubleFunction is of type:

```
doubleFunction :: (Num a) => (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can, and it's so common and deeply ingrained in the language that you don't even notice it!

For instance, when you write

```
mean :: Double -> Double -> Double
mean a b = (a + b) / 2
```

What you're really doing is, you define a function

```
mean :: Double -> EndoDouble
mean a = meanA
 where meanA b = (a + b) / 2
```

where the type of `meanA`,

```
type EndoDouble = Double -> Double
```

happens to be a function type.

So, any "multi-parameter function" in Haskell really is a single-parameter function that returns a function! The concept is called [*Currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you might have heard about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can: functions are values in Haskell, so it can be as simple as

```
functionIdentity :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
functionIdentity f = f
```

...which is just a specialised identity function.

You may also "explicitly" return a function by using a lambda if you wish, like `const`:

```
const x = \_ -> x
```